# Active profile not getting set during mvn test

Tags: spring-boot, maven, yaml, karate, spring-boot-test

I am currently doing karate testing, and while running my tests with active profile set to as "local" the application tries to boot up with active profile: "prd".

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.profiles=local
```

When I run my application with the above command the active profile is correctly set to local.

```
mvn test -Dspring-boot.run.profiles=local -Dkarate.env=local  -Pkarate
```

When I run my karate test with the above command, the application tries to boot up with active profile set to as "prd", which is the last available profile in the yaml file. When I change the order of profiles in the yaml file, still the last available profile is fetched during boot up.

Comment: Wait...typos(mobile)! Originally u had/for spring-boot-maven-plugin is good `-Dspring-boot.run.profiles=foo,bar` ... for "other plugin's", you have to use `-Dspring.profiles.active=foo,bar`

Comment: [1](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.1.RELEASE/maven-plugin/examples/run-profiles.html),[2](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.profiles)

Comment: Welcome! ..maybe also interesting for you [`ActiveProfiles` test (only!) annotation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/testing.html#spring-testing-annotation-activeprofiles)...it has high precedence, but you have to set them at compile (not run-) time.